# Solr Trouble with searching contens containing dot

Tags: solr, lucene

Hi [All clever people on stack overflow]

I'm working on a project where i have some contents separated by a dot [.],
So I'm trying to search for contents like [word.tk] it's used for a tagging system in contents.
These tags are stored in a separate dynamic field

```
{
    "ts_ticker_market": "word.tk",
    "ts_market":        "tk",
    "ts_ticker":        "word",
    "ds_date":          "2007-07-30T21:00:00Z",
    "ts_ar_search":     "en word.tk tk words qnb clarifies:",
    "ts_search":        "en word.tk tk words qnb clarifies: ...",
    "content":          "en word.tk tk words qnb clarifies: ...",
},
```

The search query might look something like this where $term is word.tk:

```
{!boost b=recip(ms(NOW,ds_date),3.16e-11,1,0.5)}
    (
        ts_ticker_market:($term)^200
        OR ts_market:($term)^175
        OR ts_ticker_market:($term)^125
        OR ts_ticker:($term)^50
        OR ts_ticker:($term*)^25
        OR ts_title:($term)^4
        OR ts_body:($term)^2
        OR ts_search:($term)^1
    )
```

I'm getting a

```
analyzer returned too many terms for multiTerm term: word.tk"
```

I hope someone can help me out with this?

EDIT:
A little more info as requested:
schema.xml analyzer

```
<analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
      add enablePositionIncrements=true in both the index and query
      analyzers to leave a 'gap' for more accurate phrase queries.
    -->
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            protected="protwords.txt"
            generateWordParts="1"
            generateNumberParts="1"
            catenateWords="1"
            catenateNumbers="1"
            catenateAll="0"
            splitOnCaseChange="0"
            preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            protected="protwords.txt"
            generateWordParts="1"
            generateNumberParts="1"
            catenateWords="0"
            catenateNumbers="0"
            catenateAll="0"
            splitOnCaseChange="0"
            preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="multiterm">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
            protected="protwords.txt"
            generateWordParts="1"
            generateNumberParts="1"
            catenateWords="0"
            catenateNumbers="0"
            catenateAll="0"
            splitOnCaseChange="1"
            preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What analyzer type are you using for your schema fields?

Comment: I have added the analyzer from the schema so hope this helps.

Comment: Customize your analyzer and not to omit `.`

Comment: I might be stupid, but I can't find anything about setting the analyzer to not omit `.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to follow up, I was unable to do a search on something with a dot `.` separation in. In the end I ended up breaking it up over multiple field and add different boosters to each field in Solr.

My search ended up being something like this. A bulky but it gets the job done.

```
ts_search:( $term )^0.01
 OR ts_ticker:( $term )^0.3
 OR ts_market:( $term )^0.2
 OR ts_ticker_market:( $term )^0.4
 OR ts_ticker:( $term*)^0.09
 OR ts_market:( $term*)^0.04
 OR ts_ticker_market:( $term*)^0.16
 OR ts_company_name_ar:( $term )^0.01
 OR ts_company_name_en:( $term )^0.01
```

Lucky for me, the text was split-able, and each section was important. The problem was that the Solr was unable to search because it got returned to many results with the same score on all of them, either 0, or some insanely high value.

This way everything gets a more separated score.